# Can Flagged Comments please appear on the "Flag Summary" Screen?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, flag-history

As per the question title. Comment Flags are not longer affecting flag weight, so this request is now useless.

Comment: I flag comments *all the time*. Especially [those obnoxious ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910302/problem-accessing-class-method) where people complain that the user doesn't meet their arbitrary accept rate threshold, and therefore they're not going to try to answer their question.

Comment: If they don't hard delete comments from db, this should be possible.

Comment: Comments are soft-deleted, but I believe are only visible to developers.

Comment: Moderators can see deleted comments for any post on a special page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now happens as shown in [More informative flagging history for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180377/more-informative-flagging-history-for-comments).

Previously, it seemed that comments were deleted but there was some work done recently on how flags are stored. This can now be found in your flagging history.