# My profile indicates 1 helpful flag, but my flagging summary is empty

Tags: support, profile-page, helpful-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does empty “Flagging Summary” page mean when “helpful flags” is “1”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/what-does-empty-flagging-summary-page-mean-when-helpful-flags-is-1)

On my Stack Overflow profile, I can see I have 1 helpful flag. However, the flagging summary/history page behind this number is empty. What could be the reason?

Comment: A "helpflug" flag - is that like some sort of [airborne](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flug) help flag?

Comment: Duplicate question, but no (real) answer provided on that one.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald A question shouldn't be reposted just because it doens't have a (real) answer (or for any other reason). Instead of posting a duplicate, you could use a bounty on the original question to draw attention to the issue.

Comment: I had not seen that one when posting, but next time will do that, thanks.

Comment: I would suggest closing the other question, because the answer given here are helpful.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald The eventual result will likely be a merging of the questions, with this answer being moved to the other question ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1388/167443))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to RivieraKid's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126152/), **comment flags do not show up in the "summary" list** (even though they *do* count towards your helpful flags count).  So, if your only helpful flag was a comment flag, that is why that list is still empty (although I would expect it to be in the "flagging history" area on the right).

If you don't like that your comment flags aren't shown in the summary, you could support this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): [Flagging history should include comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120617/flagging-history-should-include-comment-flags).

---

Further indication that your one flag was on a comment - I just noticed you do not have the "Citizen Patrol" badge (which is for flagging a post).

Comment: The feature request you're thinking of is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90112/can-flagged-comments-please-appear-on-the-flag-summary-screen), but no one cares anymore because they stopped calculating and displaying flag weight.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks!  That is one of the one's I had read, good find.  TimStone pointed me to another one [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/905343#905343).  I've added a link to that one, as it still seems to be relevant.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Can I see what the comment flag was about? I am just curious...

Comment: @AGuy unless the feature request I linked to is implemented, I don't know of a way for you to see what comment it was that you flagged.

Answer (score 2):

If you've been to [your "Flagging Summary"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/182542), surely you've seen the following note under "Your flagging history" in the right-hand margin of the page?

> * older flags were not recorded helpful/declined

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting, [I don't see that asterisk](http://i.stack.imgur.com/drMRP.jpg).  I wonder if it has to do with your account's age?

Comment: No, the page is totally empty. What is meant by "older flags"?

Comment: @jadarnel: Ah yes, probably so. My accounts that I created more recently on the SE 2.0 sites don't have that footnote, either. This answer might not apply in the asker's case here, then.