# Why my Flagged Posts page is empty?

Tags: support, flag-history, helpful-flags

I have 2 helpful flags in Stack Overflow profile. When I click on helpful flags link am not able to see any information of the target page. Why is it so?

My Profile Page,

> [image]

My Flag Summary

> [image]

Comment: Screenshot would be better instead of link.

Comment: Caching? I am afraid only mods and devs can see your flagging history.

Comment: We cannot see your flag summary, that is private information (only you and diamond moderators can see that page).

Comment: Do you remember what you flagged? If only questions then when they get deleted you can't see them anymore and I believe it's hidden from the flagging history page due to this.

Comment: added screenshots...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience (don't have the reference):

It is because they were flags on comments. The only flags shown are on questions/answers. I think it is kind of a bug.

Update:

You do not have the 'Citizen Patrol' badge which is given for first post flag, so it makes sense they were flags to comments.

Also, I just found a reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126156/209901

> In addition to RivieraKid's
>   [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126152/), **comment flags do
>   not show up in the "summary" list** (even though they *do* count
>   towards your helpful flags count).  So, if your only helpful flag was
>   a comment flag, that is why that list is still empty (although I would
>   expect it to be in the "flagging history" area on the right).

---

Just discovered that you can see your flag history, even whithout any accepted flag, in:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<your_id>
```

Comment: You may be right but then it should show on the right side, that "X Comment Flagged"

Comment: +1, Yes I think your answer is correct.

Comment: @fedorqui +1 and ans.  I think u are right .I have not flaged any answer or question.So the flag is of comment and flags of comment are not shown

Comment: Exactly. The only strange thing is that there should appear a summary in the right like `2 comments flagged // 2 deemed helpful`. Maybe it is a bug, because it does appear when you have accepted flags on posts.