# Flagging history is not showing if we have only flagged comment

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, flag-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Flagged Comments please appear on the “Flag Summary” Screen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90112/can-flagged-comments-please-appear-on-the-flag-summary-screen)
>   [What does empty “Flagging Summary” page mean when “helpful flags” is “1”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/what-does-empty-flagging-summary-page-mean-when-helpful-flags-is-1)

Recently I flagged few comments in [sports.stackexchange.com](http://sports.stackexchange.com). Which were deemed helpful. (I can see helpful flags 4 in my profile page.). When I click on helpful flags count (i.e. `4`) it does not show me summary like this.

[image]

This may be because I have not flagged any post yet. I think this should be included even if we have not flagged any post.