# Flagging history summary empty when having only comment flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, meta, comment-flags, flag-history

In my flagging history on Meta, I currently have 15 helpful and 2 declined flags. When I visit my flagging history page, the summary in right column is missing. I think the reason is I flagged only comments so far, because on SO the summary is there. I want to see how many flags of which resolution I have.

This is not a browser bug. When I look into HTML source, the `<table id="flag-stat-info-table">` is missing after `<h2>Your flagging history</h2>`.

---

My question looks pretty much like a dupe of [Flagging history is not showing if we have only flagged comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158786/238706), but I think it is not as both the possible dupe and the supposed originals were asked before the [early 2013 huge flag refactoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180377/238706) when comments were not shown on flagging history page at all.

---

I was not sure if this should be marked as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), so I chose not to wait to get [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and marked it [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) right away. If you are sure it is a bug, please feel free to mark it so.